# Which One Is Better Performance Wise: setOnClickListener VS android:onclick="onClick"

Tags: android, performance, onclicklistener

In Android we have 2 ways to set an onClick event for a buttom (or any other view I think):

**Scenario one (programmatically):**

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**Scenario two (in the XML file):**

```
<Button android:onClick="handler" />
```

Is there any performance penalty for doing this in XML or programmatically or is it the same?

Comment: I am not an expert in any way, but I would say the programmatically way is better in performance... basically is the same, but in the XML way you add one step, i think, the one in wich the XML is parsed. but I might be wrong, i am only speculating.

Comment: I don't think that it makes a significant difference. If you're running into performance problems that is not the way to solve them. I guess that if you're using that much Buttons for it to make a difference then the real problem is your layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are the same in performance. Xml is pre-parsed into binary code while compiling. so there is no over-head in Xml.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to know is through unit tests.. It totally depends on how its been handled underneath... If i'm not guessing it right, declaring it in xml could be bit slower since the xml needs to be parsed and then method should be called.. Still can't be sure, its a pure android OS designer choice

Comment: You may be correct, but the preparsing is done only once on compule time. When the app is published as an APK it is already binary code.